# working with loaddata is not working properly

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have file on local desktop.

I'm converting its url by using `[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath]` but I'm getting error. Here is my code:

```
NSString* filePath = @"/Users/Desktop/bb.ppt";
[powerWeb loadData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath]    
          MIMEType:@"application/vnd.ms-powerpoint"
  textEncodingName:@"utf-8"
           baseURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath]];
```

It is giving me this error:

```
error:::Operation could not be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error 100.)
error:::Frame load interrupted.
```

Comment: Do you actually have a user named Desktop with a PowerPoint document in his home folder?

Comment: I think you are onto the answer there Chuck :P

Comment: sorry whoever formatter first, I've submitted a bit later and overwrote your formatting ...

Comment: @madhu look how nice is your question formatted, you might even get answers now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following may work for you:

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"mypresentation" withExtension:@"ppt];
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that this is not right:

```
baseURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath]
```

You are using the same full path in `loadData` and `baseURL` parts.

Do you have a file at the location: `/Users/Desktop/bb.ppt`, even if you had it there I suspect it will try to access `/Users/Desktop/bb.ppt/Users/Desktop/bb.ppt` looking at the `baseURL` setting.

Comment: yes. i agree with stefanB. i have file at location.
but -(void)loadData:(NSData *)data MIMEType:(NSString *)MIMEType textEncodingName:(NSString *)encodingName baseURL:(NSURL *)baseURL
is predefined method. is there any another method to display pptfile.?

Comment: have you tried to tweak the parameters? I haven't look at the doc but will it work when you pass baseURL:nil ?

Answer (score 0):

I use this code to display ppt in iPhone application:

> [myWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest
>   requestWithURL:[NSURL
>   fileURLWithPath:tempFilePath]]];

But it have a leak when viewing. I don't know why.